# .NET framework (Uninstallable kind of Application?)

Tags: .net, asp.net

So the windows have different versions of .net framework, 1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 along with Service packs for particular frameworks. 
Now my windows have several versions of the said frameworks and what confuses me is that are these uninstallable or installable? Can I remove older versions If I am just using let's say 3.5 or 4.0 with ASP.NET and Visual Studio?

One more question, Do windows relies on .net framework? I mean can my machine work if it doesn't have any .net framework? :)

Comment: Is it just to save space? I think you might break some programs written in older versions by deleting these.

Comment: @simendsjo, not to save space but trying to understand the mechanics of .net framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the answers, I feel that it is quite confusing topic, so will try to give my own answer.

First, what do you call by the version of .NET Framework? In fact, it can mean several things:

1. The stuff in *Add/Remove programs* (*Uninstall a program* in *Programs and Features* under Windows 7) control panel item or the stuff in *Turn Windows features on or off* list.
2. The set of installed components.
3. The setup executable you would download from Microsoft website when you want to install .NET Framework.
4. The CLR. See the great comment by *Nate Bross* to the answer posted by *simendsjo* on this page for more details.

Depending of what do you mean by .NET Framework version, the answer will be different.

1. In *Uninstall a program* and *Turn Windows features on or off*, you can probably find one or two latest versions. Currently, I have .NET Framework 3.5.1 as "Windows feature", and .NET Framework 4.0 in "Uninstall a program". I would not expect any other versions here, since a program compiled for .NET Framework 2.0 will run fine on a machine with .NET Framework 3.5. As a proof, compile a Hello World targeting .NET Framework 2.0 and start it: it starts.
2. In `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework`, you would rather find every version, from 1.0.3705 to 4.0. Why? Because every new version of the framework adds features to the older versions, instead of rewriting everything. Here, I would strongly discourage to remove even the directory *v2.0.50727*. Probably the most recent programs written in Visual Studio 2010 and compiled to run with .NET Framework 4.0 still require 2.0 components.
3. When downloading .NET Framework setup executable, you don't have to think about older versions, as well as you don't have to download every version from 1.0 to 4.0. Download only the most recent one, it will be fine.

Note: it is essential to understand that the different versions are not standalone, but rather change or add something from/to the older versions. That's all the stuff about references to .NET Framework assemblies. For example, you could have a strange situation: a basic application which uses WCF (WCF was released in .NET 3.0) runs well on a machine which has only .NET Framework 2.0 installed, but crashes *only* when trying to execute something related to WCF: assemblies are loaded on demand, so until you require a component from .NET Framework 3.0, components from older versions will be used.

Hope this makes things easier to understand.

> One more question, Do windows relies
>   on .net framework? I mean can my
>   machine work if it doesn't have any
>   .net framework? :)

The operating system itself does not need .NET Framework to function properly. But some components require .NET Framework. As ChrisF said, *Microsoft XPS Viewer/Printer* is an example. *Microsoft Live Writer* is another one.

Comment: I don't believe this is 100% correct.  Checking on an XP VM to confirm now, but I believe if you only have 4.0 installed, and you compile to 3.5 or below it won't run.

Comment: Well, nevermind.  Apparently I screwed up my .NET installation on the virtual machine somehow.  The uninstaller for 3.5 crashes about 70% of the way through. Go MS! :p

Comment: :p Good luck. Well, before writing my answer, I quickly tested running a Hello World targeting .NET 2.0 on my machine (Win7, .NET 3.5 & 4.0), and the program runs fine. Now, maybe the results are different for a .NET 3.5 app running in .NET 4.0-only environment.

Comment: Okay, finally got it up and working.  Windows XP, Uninstalled 3.5, uninstalled 3.0, uninstalled 2.0.  Installed 4.0.  Executing console app compiled to .NET 3.5 gives the following message box: "To run this application, you first must install one of the following versions of the .NET Framework:

  v2.0.50727



Would you like to download and install version v2.0.50727 of the .NET Framework now?"

Comment: Ok, I got it (I hope). See the great comment by *Nate Bross* to the answer posted by *simendsjo*. In fact, I tested a .NET 2.0 app with .NET 3.5 & 4.0. *"FX 3, 3.5, and 3.5SP1 are also along side CLR 2.0"*, so it worked fine for me. On the other hand, *"FX 4 is alongside CLR 4"*, so in your case, CLR 2.0 is missing, making it impossible to start applications relying on it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed the latest framework (4.0), you don't need to install previos versions. I'm not sure you can remove previos version have installed after installing the latest framework: I'm not sure add/remove program control panel applet displays that versions.

And second question: few application in Windows Vista and Windows 7 depends on .NET framework, but Windows itself doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

While the different versions of the .NET framework are separate, certain applications require that they all are present on a machine:

> If you are installing Microsoft XPS Viewer (which requires Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0) on Windows XP or Windows Server 2003 and do not have previous versions of .NET Framework (1.1 and 2.0) installed, you will be asked to download them during the install process. (45 MB)

[Source](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/xps/viewxps.mspx)

> One more question, Do windows relies on .net framework? I mean can my machine work if it doesn't have any .net framework? :)

XP certainly doesn't - it predates .NET by several years.

Vista and Windows 7 include .NET 3, so in one sense they do rely on it, but as it's a feature you can turn off (thanks MainMa) there don't.

Comment: "but as the framework is part of the operating system you can't not install it": are you sure? .NET Framework 3 is part of the OS, but as some other parts, it is in *Turn Windows features on or off* list, and so I would expect it to be able to be removed (otherwise it would not be in this list, isn't it?).

Comment: @MainMa - good point - I don't have access to a Vista or 7 machine to double check.

Answer (score 0):

Just found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/kb00829019.aspx)

> **Note** Most of the time, you can use the latest version of the .NET Framework to run applications that were created by using earlier versions of the .NET Framework.

So I would think it's best to leave them. But then again... How many 1.0 programs do you have installed? :)

Comment: There are different versions of the Framework and the CLR. i.e. FX 2.0 is along side CLR 2.0; but FX 3, 3.5, and 3.5SP1 are also along side CLR 2.0. FX 4 is alongside CLR 4. So removing old versions is a BAD idea.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly 2.0 and 3.0 are required for 3.5.

4.0 can exist on it's own.

I think 1.1 depends on 1.0 as well.

I know for sure XP doesn't rely on any .NET framework to operate, but I'm not sure about Vista/7

Edit:

Just did some testing on an XP Virtual Machine.  Interesting results... With only 2.0 and 4.0 installed, I was able to run a console app compiled to 3.5.  If I use LINQ however (or I suspect any library not in 2.0) it crashes when the method is called.  If the code that uses LINQ isn't called, it doesn't crash.

With only 4.0 installed and nothing else, the same app gives the following message when run:

> To run this application, you first
>   must install one of the following
>   versions of the .NET Framework:
>
> v2.0.50727
>
> Would you like to download and install
>   version v2.0.50727 of the .NET
>   Framework now?

Clicking yes brings up the page to download .NET... except it's the .NET 4.0 download page...

Comment: So that means every framework 1.1, 2.0, 3.5... runs dependently on other versions and have connections between them. Earlier I've been thinking all every version exist independently and in their own 'home'.

Comment: Yes.  I'm not sure about 1.0/1.1 but if you have no framework and you install 3.5, it will also install 2.0 and 3.0.  3.0 and 3.5 build on top of 2.0, whereas 4.0 is independent of the others.  However only having 4.0 means you can only run apps that are compiled for 4.0 and not previous .net versions

Comment: @Zai added some test results on a virtual machine